# Trigger change event when key pressed in knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, binding, observable

I am trying to trigger change event when key is pressed. I subscribed to the observable as shown below but it only detect change after focus is changed.

Edit: for an option binding:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" data-bind="inputmask: { value: homePhone, mask: selectedHomePhoneFormat }"/>
```

in js:

```
self.homePhone = ko.observable('');
```

Subscribe:

```
 self.homePhone.subscribe(function (newvalue) {
    console.log("changed", newvalue);
});
```

Above code only detect change after I change focus. I want it to detect change every time when key pressed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Knockout.js key press event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73747957/knockout-js-key-press-event)

Answer (score -2):

```
**cshtml**
<textarea data-bind="value: homePhone ,valueUpdate: 'keyup'"></textarea>

**VM**
this.homePhone.subscribe(function () {
//your method
});
```

Comment: Please do not post code-only answers. While your solution may work, answers should also provide some explanation of why the code will resolve the issue raised in the question.